# How to download a report from Salesforce with Python and select the Timeframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, salesforce, soql

I'm trying to create a Python code to download some reports from Salesforce.

The download itself works well (using simple-salesforce), but I cannot find a way to select the From and To dates, like I would do manually (see in the picture below).

[Salesforce Timeframe selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppfm2.png)

I have some reports where I would like just to select "Today", but I also have a more complicated one where the From is the beginning of the quarter (02 May 2022) and the To is last Saturday to date.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Done, hopefully the picture will make it more clear